# Why action bar for main activity in android shows back button?

Tags: android

Why does the `ActionBar` for my main `Activity` in my android app show the back button?
It takes up space crowding out necessary buttons and is meaningless for a launcher `Activity`.
The manifest only declares it for child activities.
My minimum API is 11 and target API is 19. I am using the support library 19.01.

Manifest Code:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.myco.mypkg.MyListActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

[image]

I set

`actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);`

but the space the back arrow occupied is vacant - I want the logo to move left and occupy it.

[image]

As you can see, there is no room for a Help '?' icon and the title is clipped.

Comment: post some relevant code

Comment: `setHomeButtonEnabled(false)`?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno I add it and get `Call requires API level 14 (current min is 11): android.app.ActionBar#setHomeButtonEnabled` should I add an annotation - which one?

Comment: I had `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` removed it and now it is better - back arrow no longer shows. However, the space occupied by it remains so the problem is not fixed.

Comment: your problem is fixed now?

Comment: @MarcoAcierno no, it is not fixed. thanks for your answer. see screenshot

Comment: @MarcoAcierno is there any way to force that the title will not be clipped?

Answer (score 2):

As simple as it can be

It shows a back button i.e. more precisely the up button or navigation,  because through your code you want to show it.

Mostly in such cases, the up button approach in main activity is used to show a sliding drawer or menu, so I guess you are using something like that.

If you do not want to show it,

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Comment: the space it took up remains. please see the screenshots I added.

Comment: @likejiujitsu the space will be there as per default android values, try custom action bar layouts if you want to fully customize the action bar view. :)

Comment: how to ensure the title is displayed fully?

Comment: @likejiujitsu remove the other Actionbar buttons, reduce the title size, it also depends on what screen size you testing. On nexus 5 screen that won't crop ever, as much I know.

Comment: sorry, that wasn't the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 14) {
     getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

This will disable the "Up" Navigation for all the API levels that support it.

To remove the icon also, add this to the styles.xml:

```
 <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
<item name="displayOptions">showHome|homeAsUp|showTitle</item>
<item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item> <--this does the magic
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion - the logo does not move left. As you can see, there is no room for a Help '?' icon and the title is clipped.